# Youtube/Vimeo API limitations

Tags: youtube, thumbnails, vimeo

I want to heavily use the Vimeo API (and possibly YouTube too), to get thumbnails for videos. So my question is, are there any limitations to how many calls you can make to both of the services?

I've read on a YouTube FAQ that

> If your application does send API traffic in excess of the quota
>   limits, the API will return a too_many_recent_calls error

My problem with this is that I'm not sure that I actually use the API for YouTube. I get my thumbnail from an URL, which I'm not sure it's qualifying as an API call. The url is something like: http://img.youtube.com/vi/ORdY5xWzKzY/0.jpg

But on Vimeo I'm sure I use the API.

Any ideas to what the limitations are?

Comment: same question here re img.youtube...

Comment: I had this in production for over a year now, on a heavy traffic website, and there was no report of the images from img.youtube.com not loading. I can't guarantee it though :)